# Storing check status of toDo list

Tags: ios, swift, list, storage, status

I am developing a new screen in my app and I wanted to consult with you the best way to do it.
The new screen is going to be a static checklist and I want the user to check "step-by-step" (i.e. line-by-line) that he completed the step.

I have 2 view controller 
VC1 = theme static list 
VC2 = step static list linked to each step
--> you click on VC1.Theme1 and then it displays VC2.step1,2,3, etc.. in a static tableview.

What I want to do is:
1. checking steps in VC2 and "keep them in memory"
2. when all steps in VC2 are checked updated the status of the theme in VC1

If for 2. it is a simple calculation I am wondering what would be the best method to store the status of the step completion. I am hesitating between a database (custom) or the phone memory... I have not enough experience to know if there are other options or what is the best practice.

Any advise?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the most simple way is to use [UserDefaults](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/).

I usually use it for simple data storage. For a start I think it's a good solution for you. For example you may store an array of Bools which indicates whether steps are checked or not. Or store a counter (int) that will indicate quantity of checked steps and compare it to total of steps in the VC2.

How to write to user defaults:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard()
defaults.set(yourValue, forKey: "valueKey")
```

And read:

```
defaults.value(forKey: "valueKey")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Tung Fam , it helps a lot. I am already storing some data in the userDefaults after the call of my DB in order to access it quickly.
I am just wondering how this storage method is good since I cannot make statistic on it (on admin side) nor keep the data in case of system restore, right?

Comment: @Nati if you need to get those data to your servers then may be it's better to use firebase. as for keeping the data, you may try to use iCloud storage. check out here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know that possibility! sounds like a good solution!!! Thank you, have a nice day!